# WordPress Media upload return async-upload.php error 404

Tags: php, wordpress

When i try to upload a file bigger than 120MB, i have this error on my console :

`POST https://www.website.com/wp-admin/async-upload.php 404`

I have checked with FTP and async-upload.php file exists.

I have checked with my hosting and the file size limit is 512MB, so i don't know how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

For wordpress, it may be due to the execution timeout problem. (since your file is a bit large in size)

Please add the following to .htaccess and see the effect

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Comment: Hello, my max_execution_time is set to 1000 and same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Really strange problem, i just check and the file is presents on the FTP